# Namespace collisions

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

How is it possible that .NET is finding the wrong `MyType` in this scenario?

I have a type `A.B.C.D.MyType` in a project that I'm working on, and I'm referencing a DLL that has a type `A.B.MyType`. I do not have any `using A.B;` statements anywhere in my code, and I do have `using A.B.C.D;`. When I compile, the compiler thinks any naked reference to `MyType` means `A.B.MyType`.

I know I could just rename the class or use an alias, but I'm wondering how this is even possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you working in a namespace that is under A.B namespace? (for example A.B.X) if so the C# namespace resolutions ([ECMA-334 C# Language Specification : 10.8 10.8 Namespace and type names](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf)) says:

> ... for each namespace N, starting
>   with the namespace in which the
>   namespace-or-typename occurs,
>   continuing with each enclosing
>   namespace (if any), and ending with
>   the global namespace, the following
>   steps are evaluated until an entity is
>   located...

and then followed by:

> If K is zero and the namespace
>   declaration contains an
>   extern-alias-directive or
>   using-aliasdirective that associates
>   the name I with an imported namespace
>   or type, then the
>   namespace-or-type-name refers to that
>   namespace or type

This means that name resolution starts at the current namespace and searches all namespaces up to the root, and only after this hierarchical search ends, then the namespaces imported with the `using` clause are searched.

The following example prints "Ns1.Foo"

```
using Ns1.Foo.Foo2;

namespace Ns1.Foo
{
    class Foo
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Ns1.Foo");
        }
    }
}

namespace Ns1.Foo.Foo2
{
    class Foo
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Ns1.Foo.Foo2");
        }
    }
}

namespace Ns1.Foo.Bar
{
    class Bar
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            new Foo().Print();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Bar().Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding a using clause **inside** a namespace, will make so that the namespace is searched before the hierarchical search of current namespace is done is done. Change the example to:

```
namespace Ns1.Foo.Bar
{
    using Ns1.Foo.Foo2;
    class Bar
    {
        public void Print()
        {
            new Foo().Print();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            new Bar().Print();
        }
    }
}
```

and `Ns1.Foo.Foo2` will be printed.

Edit: changed example

Answer (score 6):

Is your code in namespace `A.B` or `A.B.C`? If so, that's probably the issue. Use a using directive like this:

```
using TheTypeIWant = A.B.C.D.MyType;
```

then just refer to `TheTypeIWant` in your code.

EDIT: I've just tried the "`using MyType=A.B.C.D.MyType`" option, but that *doesn't* work. The above is fine though.

Comment: I don't think this works with generic classes, right?

Comment: @WillIAm: Not if you want the alias to still be generic, if you see what I mean. But answering the question that was asked, there was no indication that generics were involved. A question with a concrete example using generics would probably lead to a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: in your project properties, is the "default namespace" set to A.B ?