# Absolute/outer and inner namespace confusion in C#

Tags: c#

```
using Foo.Uber;

namespace MyStuff.Foo
{
    class SomeClass{
        void DoStuff(){
            // I want to reference the outer "absolute" Foo.Uber
            // but the compiler thinks I'm refering to MyStuff.Foo.Uber
            var x = Foo.Uber.Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

How could I solve this? Just moving the using statement inside my namespace doesn't help.

Comment: Something like using Foo.Uber = FooUber; => see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262469/namespace-collisions

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do this using a [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx) (typically [`global::`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)) to refer to the default / root namespace:

`global::Foo.Uber`

Comment: Thanks, first and best solution for my case. PS: I liked the unedited answer too. :p

Answer (score 3):

You can actually specify the full path via the [**root namespace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d941h9d%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
var x = global::Foo.Uber.Bar();
```

> **Namespaces Overview**
>
> A namespace has the following
>   properties:
>
> - They organize large code projects.
> - They are delimited with the . operator.
> - The **using directive** means you do not need to specify the name of the
>     namespace for every class.
> - The **global** namespace is the "root" namespace: **global::system**
>     will always refer to the .NET
>     Framework namespace **System**.

I prefer this over aliases because when you read it, you know exactly what is going on. Aliases can be easy to misunderstand if you skip over the definition.

Answer (score 3):

Alias the namespace in the using statement:

```
using ThatOuterFoo = Foo.Uber;
...
...
//Some time later...
var x = ThatOuterFoo.Bar();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [using alias directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
using Outer = Foo.Uber;

namespace MyStuff.Foo
{
    class SomeClass{
        void DoStuff(){                
            var x = new Outer.Bar(); //outer class
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Aliaseseseseseses

```
using Foo.Uber;
using FooUberBar = Foo.Uber.Bar

namespace MyStuff.Foo
{
    class SomeClass{
        void DoStuff(){
            // I want to reference the outer "absolute" Foo.Uber
            // but the compiler thinks I'm refering to MyStuff.Foo.Uber
            var x = FooUberBar();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an alias in your using directive as described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx).